# I'm getting Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

This is my code which throws Runtime(NZEC) exception. It gives correct output in my vs code ide but when i run it in codechef's ide it throws Runtime exception.

Here is my code

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */
import java.util.*;

class meetFriends {
    public static void time() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // System.out.println("Enter the meeting time");
        String p = sc.nextLine();
        // System.out.println("Enter total friends");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String time[] = new String[n];
        // System.out.println("Enter time for each friend");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            time[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        String fmt = p.substring(6); 
        int hr = Integer.parseInt(p.substring(0, 2));
        int min = Integer.parseInt(p.substring(3, 5));

        if(fmt.equals("AM")) {
            hr = hr % 12;
        } else {
            hr = (hr % 12) + 12;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < time.length; j++) {
            String fmtL = time[j].substring(6, 8);
            String fmtR = time[j].substring(15);
            int hrL = Integer.parseInt(time[j].substring(0,2));
            int hrR = Integer.parseInt(time[j].substring(9,11));
            int minL = Integer.parseInt(time[j].substring(3,5));
            int minR = Integer.parseInt(time[j].substring(12,14));
            if(fmtL.equals("AM")) {
                hrL = hrL % 12;
            } else {
                hrL = (hrL % 12) + 12;
            }

            if(fmtR.equals("AM")) {
                hrR = hrR % 12;
            } else {
                hrR = (hrR % 12) + 12;
            }

            if((hr*60+min) >= (hrL*60+minL) && (hr*60+min) <= (hrR*60+minR)) {
                System.out.print(1);
            } else {
                System.out.print(0);
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        in.close();
    } 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scan.nextInt();
        while(t-- != 0) {
            time();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

This is the error if i use sc.nextLine():

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at meetFriends.time(Main.java:9)
    at meetFriends.main(Main.java:60)
```

And if i use sc.next() in place of sc.nextLine() this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at meetFriends.time(Main.java:9)
    at meetFriends.main(Main.java:60)
```

This is the questions link https://www.codechef.com/FEB21C/problems/MEET

I am not asking for any solution/logic of the problem just some help with NZEC.

Comment: 2 Scanners? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to create a two scanner class objects .